# Is this inequality related to $|\log \zeta (s)|$ wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

This is a doubt in the Littlewood's first estimate(in which it is assumed that Riemann hypothesis is true)  given in [this book](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Equivalents_of_the_Riemann_Hypothesis_Vo.html?id=--k4DwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y), page 433.

Let $s = \sigma + it$ and $\delta $ such that $\frac12 + \delta \le \sigma \le 1,$ and $t$ is sufficiently large.

We apply Borel Caratheodory theorem to $\log \zeta(s)$ with circles $|z - (2+it)| = \frac32 -\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $|z - (2+it)| = \frac32 -\delta$

It has been already proved that $|\zeta(s)| \ll_A t^A$ on the outer circle where $A > 0$. So by Borel Caratheodory theorem we get $$|\log \zeta(s) | \le \frac{2(3-2\delta)}{\delta} A \log t + \frac{6-3\delta}{\delta}|\log \zeta(2+it)|. $$ Then the author writes the inequality $$ \frac{2(3-2\delta)}{\delta} A \log t + \frac{6-3\delta}{\delta}|\log \zeta(2+it)| < \frac{A}{\delta} \log t$$

I do not understand how to bound $|\log \zeta(2+it)|,$ and get the above inequality.

Suppose I accept the inequality and for $\delta \ne 0$ I get $$(5-4\delta) A \log t + (6-3\delta)|\log \zeta(2+it)| < 0 $$

Since, $\frac12 + \delta \le 1$ we have $\delta \le 1/2.$ So, in the above inequality the left hand side is positive which is incorrect.

I have attached the screen shot of the equation in the book.[image: Screenshot.]

Note : In [this](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Theory_of_the_Riemann_Zeta_function.html?id=1CyfApMt8JYC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) book The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function by Edward Charles Titchmarsh, D. R. Heath-Brown, page 336 the same equation is written, so I am not sure If I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Note : The above result is used in the proof of the following equivalent statement of Riemann hypothesis : $\sum_{n \le x} \mu(n)  \ll x^{\epsilon + \frac12} $ for every $\epsilon > 0$ (given by Littlewood originally).

Comment: In the inequality $\frac{2(3-2\delta)}{\delta} A \log t + \frac{6-3\delta}{\delta}|\log \zeta(2+it)| < \frac{A}{\delta} \log t$ the constant $A$ is not the same on both sides as the author mentions in the screenshot; it would be better to use $A_1$ or such for the RHS constant but in ANT sometimes stuff like this is done and can indeed cause confusion; while for the other question, trivially $\log |\zeta(2+it)| \le \log 10$  since $|\zeta(2+it)| \le \zeta (2) \le 10$ or so

Comment: To get the bound on zeta function, just use the dirichlet series.

Comment: @Conrad Indeed, I overlooked the comment of the author about the constant $A$!

Comment: @Conrad: Why is "stuff like this" done sometimes? It does not make mathematical sense.

Comment: Less in modern papers which use $<<$ and $O$ instead but more commonly in classical papers before the $O$ notation has been adopted; note that both $<<$ and $O$ can be misused and misunderstood too but in different ways

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$
\log\zeta(s)=\sum_{n\ge2}{\Lambda(n)\over\log n}\cdot{1\over n^s},
$$

for $\Re(s)>1$, so we have

$$
|\log\zeta(2+it)|\le\sum_{n\ge2}{\Lambda(n)\over\log n}\cdot{1\over n^2}=O(1).
$$